# passing in environment variables into docker running in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a dockerfile that looks like this at the moment:

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine
COPY ./ /src
ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT = "snappy-premise-118915"
RUN apk add --no-cache git && \
    apk --no-cache --update add ca-certificates && \
    cd /src && \
    go get -t -v cloud.google.com/go/pubsub && \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build main.go

# final stage
FROM alpine
ENV LATITUDE "-121.464"
ENV LONGITUDE "36.9397"
ENV SENSORID "sensor1234"
ENV ZIPCODE "95023"
ENV INTERVAL "3"
ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT "snappy-premise-118915"
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "/app/key.json"
ENV GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL "INFO"
RUN apk --no-cache --update add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /src/main /app/
COPY --from=0 /src/key.json /app/
ENTRYPOINT /app/main
```

and the pod config looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sensorpub
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sensorpub
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: google-cloud-key
        secret:
          secretName: pubsub-key
      containers:
      - name: sensorgen
        image: gcr.io/snappy-premise-118915/sensorgen:v1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          mountPath: /var/secrets/google
        env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
```

I want to be able to pass in these environment vars:

```
ENV LATITUDE "-121.464"
ENV LONGITUDE "36.9397"
ENV SENSORID "sensor1234"
ENV ZIPCODE "95023"
ENV INTERVAL "3"
ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT "snappy-premise-118915"
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "/app/key.json"
ENV GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL "INFO"
```

I want to be able to set the environment variables in the pod config so that the docker file can use those...how do I do that instead of just coding them into the docker image directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to be able to set the environment variables in the pod config so that the docker file can use those...how do I do that instead of just coding them into the docker image directly?

There is no need to specify **any** `ENV` directive in a Dockerfile; those directives only provide defaults in the case where (as in your example `PodSpec`) they are not provided at runtime.

The "how" is to do exactly what you have done in your example `PodSpec`: populate the `env:` array with the environment variables you wish to appear in the Pod

Comment: hmmm...so I removed the `ENV` from dockerfile and then pub `env:` in my `PodSpec:` but docker doesn't seem to pick those up...

Comment: How do you know it does not pick them up? Because that certainly runs counter to over 2 years of experience where I have never seen what you are describing